# Regex I want to match until certain characters but still be able to match strings if it doesn't have these characters

Tags: python, regex

in the second group, I want to match words until it encounters a ( or > symbol.
But, I still want it to match words even if it doesn't have those symbols as in strings 3 and 4.  I am using Python.

[image: regex not matching]

Comment: You are making it hard to help you. Why not post your sample text and regex as *plain text*, so we can copy and try out things easier?

Comment: Thank you for the tip and thank you blhsing for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match the end of string in an alternation instead:

```
.*(#\d*\,?\d+)\s.*in\s(.*?)\s*(?=[(>]|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BliHlU/1

Answer (score 1):

When you're matching a sequence that isn't supposed to include a character, just use a character set that inverts the characters you don't want.  I've simplified this as well based on your examples. The only downside is that the match will include trailing spaces.

```
r'.*(#\d*\,?\d+)\s+in\s+([^(>]*)'

>>> for test in tests:
    print(re.findall(r'.*(#\d*\,?\d+)\s+in\s+([^(>]*)', test))

[('#26,968', 'Office Products ')]
[('#13,452', 'Industrial & Scientific ')]
[('#99,999', 'baby')]
[('#888', 'office supplies')]
```

Comment: This matched the whole last string on the online website, but apparently works in python programming.  Thanks anyways.  It has been answered.

Comment: @timmyt123 then your problem wasn't very well specified.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best pattern and could catch on a lot more, but if the sample provided is a good sampling of the data, I have another pattern to suggest:

```
r"([#\d,]+) in ([\w\s&]+)>?([\w\s&]*)([()\w\s\d]*)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/hKD6AX/2

Hope this helps!